# Paypal ipn issue with pdt

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

i have enable both pdt and ipn for my paypal account now for some website i wanto to use ipn and for some pdt how can i differnentiate what to use please guide i see same html form for both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps [this PayPal Developer Page](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNPDTAnAlternativetoIPN/) can be of use to you. The page notes the differences between the two services and it provides examples as to when PDT is appropriate.

It is worth mentioning that PayPal (according to the page I linked) recommends the use of IPN over PDT when possible.

Using both PDT and IPN is discussed at the bottom of the page. However, the page warns that with PDT and IPN both enabled, your website will receive order confirmations twice; thus you must be careful about how you use these features.

Now, in my opinion, I believe enabling both PDT and IPN is a good tactic. PDT messages are **not** guaranteed to arrive at your server; whereas IPN messages are basically guaranteed to arrive because PayPal will resend them until your server acknowledges them. So I believe this combination is good as long as your implementation guards against double processing.

One way you can guard against double processing is by recording each transaction ID string to a database when you receive a payment. However, before processing payments, make sure you check the database to see if that transaction ID has already been recorded (and thus already processed). If it is not recorded there, insert it into the table and process the transaction. Else, exit the IPN script.